# Magento 2: Best way to change customer group event & call if needed?

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer, xml, magento-2.1.3

[Trigger event after an order has been created/saved](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/trigger-event-after-an-order-has-been-created-saved)

```
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
    <observer name="change_user_group" instance="Custom\Module\Observer\ChangeUserGroupObserver" />
</event>
```

We have 2 events `sales_order_place_after` or `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`.

What if user has refreshed the success page & if group is already changed then i don't want to call that observer.

It should not go to observer file itself.

Can we put like if condition on `events.xml`? What is alternative?

Comment: See my updated answer. We should try with Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sales_order_save_after`, check the condition directly on your observer. However, **we should try with Plugin**.

*app/code/Company/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="change_user_group"
                type="Company\Module\Model\Plugin\ChangeUserGroupPlugin"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

Your Plugin:

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Model\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class ChangeUserGroupPlugin
{

    const ID_CUSTOMER_GROUP_CHANGE = 5; // For example group

    /**
     * @var CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $_customerRepository;

    /**
     * ChangeUserGroupObserver constructor.
     * @param CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    )
    {
        $this->_customerRepository     = $customerRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $result
     * @return mixed
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function afterSave(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        if($result->getState() == Order::STATE_COMPLETE) {
            try {
                $customerId    = $result->getCustomerId();
                $customer      = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);
                $current_group = $customer->getGroupId();
                if ($current_group != self::ID_CUSTOMER_GROUP_CHANGE) {
                    $customer->setGroupId(self::ID_CUSTOMER_GROUP_CHANGE);
                    $this->_customerRepository->save($customer);
                }
            }
            catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw $e;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: In observer i already checked. Don't want to enter in Observer. But using `sales_order_save_after` if payment failed then also it changes the customer group w/o placing successfully order right?

Comment: It gives `new` order status This `if ($order->getState() === Order::STATE_COMPLETE) {` is not working

Comment: @AnkitShah you can check the state of order. In case, `new` order status, we need to check `if(in_array($order->getState(), ['new', 'completed']))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want after payment is completed successfully then you should try one of the following:

```
sales_order_invoice_pay
sales_order_invoice_save_after
sales_order_payment_place_end
```